# How to make elderberry extract

Tags: flavor, extracts, vodka, elderberries

i have some fresh elderberries and i was thinking of making an extract with them, how would I do this, i know you have to leave it sitting in vodka but at what ratio? for how long? Should I crush the berries or add anything else, would i get more flavour out of them with an extract or just using them fresh?

Answer (score 2):

Typically you'll get the most flavor using them fresh or frozen. I make fruit liqueurs with vodka, whole (or pitted & sliced - not a huge difference, really)  fruits, and sugar, and figure on them being 4-6 month projects - removing the sugar would make it pretty much an extract, and you want the most flavorless (or "neutral") vodka you can find, rather than any that carries a flavor of its own.

There, I just fill the jar with all the fruit (and sugar, for liqueurs) that will fit, and then fill with vodka. The fruit will shrink over time as the vodka draws out the juices. Leave it in a dark place.

If you have a lot of them, elderberry wine is also traditional.

Comment: The general advice is to heat elderberries before consumption. Could you please address that?

Comment: Sounds like that might be a different answer, written by someone who does it that way.